# The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

Windows 7 PC is not detecting USB drives.

Each USB drive in Device Manager indicates the following error:

```
Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. 
The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)
```

[image: Device Manager missing drivers.]

I have tried uninstalling the drivers and restarting, however the USB devices always appear the same (yellow exclamation point icon).

Comment: Have you tried installing new drivers?

Comment: Try updating USB controller driver

Comment: PC is a HP ProBook 450 G2. I have tried "USB" drivers from HP.com: Realtek USB and PCIe Media Card Reader Drivers.

Comment: after you fixed your other issue with chkdsk, now run **sfc /scannow** to make sure that no Windows files are corrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced suspect hard drive, installed Windows 7 Pro on new hard drive. USB drives now working fine.